# array returned from a server but even after serializing it to json its not converted to array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this

```
var fromList;
$.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'type': "POST",
    'global': false,
    'returnFormat': "plain",
    'url': "buildercfc.cfm?object=tables",
    'success': function (data) {
        fromList = $.trim((data));
    }
});

console.log(fromList);
```

the data is being returned from the cffunction as a ARRAY column and i am serialize to return back like this

```
["dbo.table1","dbo.table2"]
```

but jquery code is not considering it as an array, it is still dealing it as string, what is going wrong here

Comment: Maybe try adding `dataType: 'json'`? According to the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) it usually tries to auto-detect, but you can override it.

Comment: when i add it, nothing happens, it results the data same as it is doing now

Comment: What exactly does the string data look like? You show what you want it to look like, but you don't seem to be showing what it actually looks like. Also it might be useful if you can open your dev tools and show the raw response headers and response body for your AJAX call...good info to have when debugging a network request

Comment: that is the raw response is coming as as to what i showed here, in console, it does look like the above but not an array

Comment: Never ever use `async:false` ! It is a horrible practice and is deprecated by the browser vendors. You should be seeing deprecation warnings in your dev tools console

Comment: var arr = JSON.parse(data);
alert(arr.length)

Answer (score 0):

try using JSON.parse

```
var fromList;
$.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'type': "POST",
    'global': false,
    'returnFormat': "plain",
    'url': "buildercfc.cfm?object=tables",
    'success': function (data) {
        fromList = $.trim(data);
        var arr = JSON.parse(fromList); 
        alert(arr.length);
    }
});

console.log(fromList);
```